# using data from a file inside an if condition

Tags: java

i am currently working on a payroll program for my school project and i have this code:
    `

```
PrintWriter taxes = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("Tax.txt", true));
     System.out.println("You are updating Progressive Tax");
     System.out.println("Enter the number of total brackets:");
     int ammount = scan.nextInt()-1;
     for(int i=0; i<= ammount -1; i++){
         System.out.println("Enter the bracket top limit:");
         double bracket = scan.nextDouble();
         System.out.println("Enter the tax for the bracket:");
         double tax = scan.nextDouble()/100;
         taxes.println("Up to: " + String.format("%.2f", bracket));
         taxes.println("Tax percentage: " + String.format("%.2f", tax));
         if(i == ammount -1){
             System.out.println("Enter the bracket bottom limit:");
             bracket = scan.nextDouble();
             System.out.println("Enter the tax for the bracket:");
             tax = scan.nextDouble()/100;
             taxes.println("From: " + String.format("%.2f", bracket));
             taxes.println("Tax percentage: " + String.format("%.2f", tax));
        }
    }`
```

here i am storing the tax levels into a text file. what i want to do is reading the data from this file and placing it in these code:

```
 `if (baseSalary <= (to be read from file){
         insurance = (to be read from file)*baseSalary;
         social = (to be read from file)*baseSalary;
         tax = (to be read from file)*baseSalary;
    }`
```

my question is how do i put the exact values in its corresponding place?

Answer (score 0):

It will be difficult to maintain such data(insert and fetch), using `text` file.The efficient way is to go with `excel sheet` in which each `column` will handle the different record for single iteration.You can move with `Apache POI library` which is simple to read and write.I have google one example at http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-read-write-excel-file-apache-poi/

Comment: ok but how do i put the values in their corresponding places? still having troubles understanding the process

Comment: corresponding place mean column in excel ?

Comment: i have provide one link in the answer.plz follow this and if u face any pblm let me knw